# Connecting ASP.NET and Android applications to the same Database

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, restful-architecture

I am starting to build a web application with ASP.NET which will help people who are looking for rides inside a city find drivers offering rides from defined start points and destinations. The web app will contain map views to allow the users indicates their start points and destination coordinates as well as defining the route for the drivers. There will be an "On the go" mobile app which will also allow the users do the same thing from their mobile phones in addition to some mobile exclusive features e.g. notifications reminding of the ride time.

What would be the best approach to connect those two client apps to a common Database? Is using a webservice e.g. RESTful API a good idea? I'm kind of lost on what to choose as a DB Server, and what interface would be the best to connect the Web app and Android app to the same database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, DB and client are independent. So. Implement the DB, create some DAL above it and call the DAL methods in the form you wish. REST is a generally good idea, but it depends on your design wishes - REST is data based (you call an URL without sending and getting any classes), SOAP is function based - you call functions with prepared data.